# как убрать занос информации в бд при повторном обновлении страницы

Tags: php

Я делаю такую штуку:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `battle` (img,name,level,life,atk,def,type,username) SELECT img,name,level,life,atk,def,type,username FROM `enemy` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
```

Но толку ? Когда страницу обновляешь инфа опять заносится, можно как то сделать чтоб только при нажатии клавиши инфа заносилась ? Например:
 1. На экране есть клавиша *Бой*
 2. В случаи если мы хотим сразится мы тыкаем на нее и нам выводит врага 
 3. Но страница постоянно обновляется и по этому постоянно заносится инфа!Убрать обновления не мона =)

*Как сделать чтоб только при нажатии клавиши заносилась инфа? Если можно то подробно расскажите* **Заранее спасибо**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для каждого запроса делают уникальный ключ. Т.е. вот начинает работать скрипт, создается какой-то ключ и передается скрытому полю а-ля:

> $secretkey = "jng93v";
>
> и
>
> <input type="hidden" value="jng93v">

Когда запрос выполняется, он сверяет: тот ли ключ передается? Он видит, что верный и когда запрос выполнен он создает новый ключ, но поле остается то старое. Т. е.

> $secretkey = "73f48b";
>
> и
>
> <input type="hidden" value="jng93v">

Т.е. они уже не сходятся и запрос выполняться не будет. Надеюсь, вам понятна моя мысль.

Comment: хммм... момент разберусь =)

Comment: как сделать чтоб создавался ключ ?

Comment: Всмысле?
Сделай рандомное создание ключа:

function generateKey($length) {
  $chars = 'abdefhiknrstyzABDEFGHKNQRSTYZ23456789';
  $numChars = strlen($chars);
  $string = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, $numChars) - 1, 1);
  }
  return $string;
}

Потом вызывайте generateKey(5);